# Compute $\int_0^2\int_{\frac y2}^1e^{x^2}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Compute $\displaystyle \int_0^2\int_{\frac y2}^1e^{x^2}dxdy$

$\displaystyle\int_0^2\frac {e^{x^2}}{2x}{\Big|}_{\frac y2}^1dy=\int_0^2\frac e2-\frac {e^\frac {y^2}{4}}{y}dy$.

I am having trouble integrating the RHS.

Hints are appreciated!

Edit: $\displaystyle \int e^{x^2}=\frac 12e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the original integral: It is *not* true that

$$\int e^{x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2x} e^{x^2}$$

In fact, $e^{x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative. As a better approach, change the order of the integration first; you'll wind up with an integral of the form $ye^{y^2}$, which can be handled with a substitution.